# ES6 module import doesn't work with MP3 files

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-5

When trying to import an MP3 file, like so:

```
import audioSrc from "./audio.mp3";
```

I get the following error:

```
TS2792: Cannot find module './audio.mp3'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
```

However, this works:

```
const audioSrc = require("./audio.mp3");
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/joaobzrr/e01c3efd0a1cb2aff7f3dafdbd749d69) are all the files needed to reproduce this problem. Note that I'm using Webpack 5 with `ts-loader` to compile Typescript into Javascript, and that the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) says `file-loader` is deprecated and asset modules should be used instead.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why importing MP3 files works with CommonJS syntax but not with ES6?
2. If possible, how can I import MP3 files with ES6 syntax?

Comment: Can you share your repo structure + tsconfig.json file as well? It's best if you share a reproducible repo

Comment: @tmhao2005 See revised question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've missed to add the typing for asset in this case is for `mp3` file. The common solution is to create a `types` directory at the root directory with a defined file `asset.d.ts` and `include` in your configuration file:

`types/asset.d.ts`

```js
declare module "*.mp3" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*",
    "types/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nice, this works. Before I accept your answer, could you elaboporate on why this is necessary or link to some other place that talks more in-depth about this? Is there anything in the Typescript documentation about this?

Comment: Basically Typescript doesn't allow us to import asset files like images/font/media... But webpack allows us to do that so the typing above is just by passing `tsc` complier. Webpack has also mentioned in a link here https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a loader to handle the mp3 files which is `file-loader`, which can be done like this in webpack module rules.

This solution will work for webpack 4.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.mp3$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      query: {
        name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the you can import via es6 module

```
import mp3File from './file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3';
```

To make it work on webpack5:
you can use

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.mp3$/,
      type: "asset/resource",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) says: "DEPRECATED for v5: please consider migrating to asset modules".

Comment: Added updaed version for webpack 5

Comment: let me know if this works or not, I have tested worked for me on webpack 5

Comment: The way you're doing it in your revised answer is exactly what I'm doing. The problem is that the Typescript compiler doesn't like it. Try adding `ts-loader` and you will probably see the same error I'm seeing.